# Nonmember template function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class `pair`, and I'd like to write a `show` function *outside* of the class to do some fancy `cout`ing. When specifying the template type in `show` explictly, it all works as expected:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class A_Type>
class pair
{
public:
  A_Type a0;
  A_Type a1;
};

void show(const pair<double> & p) {
  std::cout << p.a0 << std::endl;
  std::cout << p.a1 << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  pair<double> p;
  p.a0 = 1.2;
  p.a1 = 1.3;

  show(p);
}
```

I'd like to have `show` oblivious of the template type though.

Any hints?

Comment: Simply `template<typename T>void show(const pair<T> & p) {`

Comment: If you promote your comment to an answer, I'll be happy to mark it a solution.

Comment: @NicoSclomer Just did

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change `show` function to:

```
template<typename DataType>
void show(const pair<DataType> & p) {
   std::cout << p.a0 << std::endl;
   std::cout << p.a1 << std::endl;
}
```

Or a better approach (in my opinion) is to make `show` function member of the class:

```
template <class A_Type>
class pair {
   public:
     A_Type a0;
     A_Type a1;

     void show() const {
         std::cout << this->a0 << std::endl;
         std::cout << this->a1 << std::endl;
     }
};
```

and then simply:

```
int main() {
   pair<double> p;
   p.a0 = 1.2;
   p.a1 = 1.3;

   p.show();
}
```

Comment: And for your opinion about member method, you may read [how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197)

Comment: @Jarod42 I just prefer `p.show()` over `show(p)` in this case. I would prefer `show(p)` if more than one classes could use it. But, again that's just my opinion.

Comment: *"I would prefer show(p) if more than one classes could use it"*. I don't understand. Do you mean you prefer `show(const pair<T>&)` if there are overloads with other type as `show(const myVector<T>&)` ? I don't understand that argument...